# API return breaks when using inner join?

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-mvc

I've been building an API which was working absolutely fine until I tried to add an inner join

The SQL I'm passing returns as I'd expect when I run it in Beaver (am using Mac)

However, when I try and access it via my API end point, instead of the combined results, I get only results from the table I added in the join

I presume am doing something really stupid ...

From my controller:

```
result = dbtest.FromDatabase(
    "SELECT A.FAMILY_ID
        ,A.START_TIME
        ,A.END_TIME
        ,A.WORKER_ID
        ,A.WEEK_NO
        ,A.ID
        ,A.SHIFT_NO
        ,A.DAY_OF_WEEK
        ,A.HOLIDAY_OR_TERM
        ,B.WORKER_NAME
    FROM SHIFT_REQ_TBL A
    INNER JOIN WORKER_TBL B ON A.WORKER_ID = B.WORKER_ID
    WHERE A.FAMILY_ID = '" + FAMILY.FAMILY_ID + "'");
```

From my model

```
if (query.Contains("SHIFT_REQ_TBL"))
{
    var tbl_type = new TimekeeperTables.SHIFT_REQ_TBL();

    tbl_type.FAMILY_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FAMILY_ID"]);
    tbl_type.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
    tbl_type.WEEK_NO = Convert.ToInt32(reader["WEEK_NO"]);
    tbl_type.WORKER_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["WORKER_ID"]);

    tbl_type.SHIFT_NO = reader["SHIFT_NO"].ToString();
    tbl_type.START_TIME = reader["START_TIME"].ToString();
    tbl_type.END_TIME = reader["END_TIME"].ToString();
    tbl_type.DAY_OF_WEEK = reader["DAY_OF_WEEK"].ToString();
    tbl_type.HOLIDAY_OR_TERM = reader["HOLIDAY_OR_TERM"].ToString();
    tbl_type.WORKER_NAME = reader["WORKER_NAME"].ToString();

    db_results.Add(tbl_type);
    jsonDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db_results);
}
```

Results (from postman)

"[{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"},{\"WORKER_ID\":1,\"WORKER_NAME\":\"UNASSIGNED\"}]"

Comment: Is the query right? I guess FAMILY_ID column is an Int column. Your query inserts FAMILY_ID as String " WHERE A.FAMILY_ID = '123' ". Remove the single quotes and try.

Comment: Yes it's an int, it works fine if the query looks simply like this: result = dbtest.FromDatabase("SELECT * FROM SHIFT_REQ_TBL A WHERE A.FAMILY_ID = '" + FAMILY.FAMILY_ID + "'");

Comment: Share the output of this simple query.

Comment: Sure. I had to edit out any reference to WORKER_NAME to stop it throwing an error, but otherwise all I did was change the string"[{\"FAMILY_ID\":1,\"SHIFT_NO\":\"ONE       \",\"START_TIME\":\"0900      \",\"END_TIME\":\"1200      \",\"DAY_OF_WEEK\":\"Monday    \",\"HOLIDAY_OR_TERM\":\"TERM      \",\"ID\":1,\"WEEK_NO\":1,\"WORKER_ID\":1},{\"FAMILY_ID\":1,\"SHIFT_NO\":\"TWO       \",\"START_TIME\":\"1200      \",\"END_TIME\":\"1700      \",\"DAY_OF_WEEK\":\"Monday    \",\"HOLIDAY_OR_TERM\":\"TERM      \",\"ID\":2,\"WEEK_NO\":1,\"WORKER_ID\":1},

Comment: So why is it returning only 2 columns when you run this query?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - that's my question too! The simple query returns eight columns, but when I join it in order to get worker name, I get only two

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I was being stupid and figured it out

I was using a really dumb way of identifying the calling URL which already was checking for SHIFT_TBL in an earlier case